# Filter Last Orders Collection on Dashboard

Tags: magento2, orders

I am developing multi-vendor site. on Order place I save seller ids of order in `sales_order` table like `1,2,3` mean in this order has 3 sellers items.

Now i filtered `Last Orders` collection in `/vendor/magento/module-reports/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Collection.php::addItemCountExpr` method  with `addFeildToFilter`
$currentloginsellerid=2;
`$this->addFieldToFilter('current_seller_id',array('finset'=>$currentloginsellerid));`

It filtered. But `Total` Column show total of this order . But i want to total of seller items. How can be possible this ? 
Can anyone guide me here please ?